# How to change Woocommerce product image when select one variation from multiple variations?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have setup e-commerce store using woocommerce in wordpress.
In this some products are variable products and I set Color, Size variations for these products and set images accordingly color and size.
Now when I select both color and size variation options then the product main image gets changed.

But I want to cange the product image when I will select only color not both options.

Is it possible to do this in Woocommerce?

Please suggest me an option in this.

Comment: Please help me if anyone have idea about this.

Comment: Hi Ashish, did you find a solution for this? I have the exact same problem. Thanks